# GitHub: force new review after code changes on a pull request

Tags: github, pull-request, review

I have a GitHub repo that requires pull requests (PRs) to be approved before they are merged. That is working great. However, sometimes the following happens:

- The PR is approved by someone, perhaps with some minor comments.
- The PR owner makes some more changes.
- Since the PR has already been approved it can be merged right away, even though the new changes have not been explicitly approved.

Is there a way to force a new review after code changes on a GitHub PR?